# Hide the all other divs except one which is clicked

Tags: php, jquery

I have list of user and their dates in PHP and onclick of specific user, I want to hide div other than one whose link is clicked
For example :

```
 <div class='person' id='add_new_date_8' style='display:none;'>
 <div class='person' id='add_new_date_9' style='display:none;'>
 <div class='person' id='add_new_date_10' style='display:none;'>

<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="addMydate('<?PHP echo $id;?>')">Add a new Date?<a/>
```

So if `$id = 8` then hide all div of class `person` which has id other than '`add_new_date_8`'

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

access id in js function. and first hide all the div with `person` class and then show the which have matching id.

```
function addMydate(id){
      $('.person').hide();
      $('#add_new_date_'+id).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Make it simple in jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.person', function() {
   $('.person').hide();
   $(this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions so far will work, however I prefer to use .siblings()

```
function addMydate(id){
  var selectedEl = $('#add_new_date'+id);
  selectedEl.siblings().hide(); //siblings() takes all other elements of the same parent
  selectedEl.show();
}
```

This will prevent the element itself from being hidden and then shown again, and might save you some headaches on animations, should you add those.

note: this depends on your HTML structure instead of classes, which is a bit less flexible. You can also use the following to exclude the element you want to show from the elements that get hidden:

```
$('.person').not('#add_new_date'+id).hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `siblings` to get the siblings of the clicked element.

```
$(document).on('click', '.person', function() {
    $(this).show().siblings('.person').hide();
});
```

> Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/siblings

**EDIT**

```
function addMydate(userId) {
    $('#add_new_date_' + userId).show().siblings('.person').hide();
}
```